# What is the regular expression to remove any string before particular pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am having below string

```
$str = '$TestSuiteObj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod Test_volumeval'
```

I need to remove `'$TestSuiteObj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod` and keep only `Test_volumeval1`

I tried to truncate few of them as below but not fully.

```
$str -replace 'Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod',''
```

How to truncate fully and keep only Test_volumeval1 in powershell?

Comment: Probably `$str -replace '.*\s+', ''`.

Comment: Or `$str.trim().split(' ')[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trimming the string and splitting it with a space, and then grabbing the last item:

```
$str.trim().split(' ')[-1]
```

However, if you want to play with regex, you may just match all characters on a line up to and including the last whitespace(s) and replace them with an empty string:

```
$str.trim() -replace '.*\s', ''
# => Test_volumeval
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5cs&i=%24TestSuiteObj+%7c+Add-Member+-MemberType+ScriptMethod+Test_volumeval&r=)

You may also use

```
$matched = $str.trim() -match '(\S+)\s*$'
```

and use the value in `$matches[1]` - the last chunkl of 1 or more non-whitespace characters.

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs*%24&i=%24TestSuiteObj+%7c+Add-Member+-MemberType+ScriptMethod+Test_volumeval&r=).

Answer (score 1):

Try with capturing group

```
$str -replace '^.*?\s(\w+)$', '$1'
```